# frame-ancestors of Content-Security-Policy is not working in Chrome, Firefox and IE

Tags: google-chrome, security, firefox, jakarta-ee, content-security-policy

Let's say my main java web application is running on machine one;
http://192.168.0.1:8080/mainapp

Other two applications are framing my main application.
Assume other two applications are running on other machine like
 
http://192.168.0.21/TrustedOne and http://192.168.0.31/TrustedTwo 
These two application is framing like

```
<html>
<body>
  <iframe src="http://192.168.0.1:8080/mainapp" width="200" height="200">
  </iframe> 
</body>
</html>
```

I want to allow framing only for http://192.168.0.21/TrustedOne and http://192.168.0.31/TrustedTwo.
So I put Content-Security-Policy header in filter class at my main java application.

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,  
FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {  

    response.addHeader("Content-Security-Policy", "frame-ancestors http://192.168.0.21/TrustedOne http://192.168.0.31/TrustedTwo"); 
    chain.doFilter(request, response);
}
```

My expecting result is that these two framing applications should get access to main application inside the iframe.

But both of these framing applications cannot access http://192.168.0.1:8080/mainapp in all of the browser; Chrome, Firefox and IE. 
All browsers blocked my main application http://192.168.0.1:8080/mainapp

Is there something is wrong my perception on frame-ancestors of Content-Security-Policy?

Comment: What is the exact error?

Answer (score 3):

The `frame-ancestors` directive can only have a host or an origin, not a URL with a path ([documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/frame-ancestors)).

Delete the path.

Comment: that means I cannot test with URL like http://192.168.0.21/TrustedOne. Can only test with domain like http://TrustedOne.com, is it ?

Comment: Or an IP address.

Comment: Are you sure that frame-ancestors can have IP address? Is there any official documentation for this?

Comment: Internet hosts by name or IP address, as well as an optional URL scheme and/or port number. The site's address may include an optional leading wildcard (the asterisk character, '*'), and you may use a wildcard (again, '*') as the port number, indicating that all legal ports are valid for the source.

Comment: As per CSP 2 document the host-source can have path part https://w3c.github.io/webappsec-csp/2/#directive-frame-ancestors